# B43 not (always) starting up correctly

Tags: 12.04, boot, broadcom

I am getting the error message:

```
b43-phy0 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog 15, Type 15, Revision 255)
```

Which would indicate a driver problem. However, this seems not to be the case since it will start sometimes, I need to reboot a few times to get it running.

To me it seems it tries to start while the device is still initializing, however I have no idea how to adjust the timing.

Answer (score 0):

This may work. Create b43.conf in /etc/modprobe.d and add

`options b43 pio=1 qos=0`